# Interpretation of darts MAPE

Tags: python, time-series, u8darts

I have fitted a lgb_model and am experimenting with the `backtest()` method from [darts](https://unit8co.github.io/darts/generated_api/darts.models.forecasting.lgbm.html#darts.models.forecasting.lgbm.LightGBMModel.backtest). Just to confirm, the output is `5.7%`, the MAPE correct?

```py
from darts.models.forecasting.lgbm import LightGBMModel
lgb_model = LightGBMModel(lags=30)
lgb_model.fit(val)

# Backtest the model
backtest_results = lgb_model.backtest(series=val)

# Print the backtest results
print(backtest_results)
```

output:

```
...
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
[LightGBM] [Warning] No further splits with positive gain, best gain: -inf
5.701803383509749
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the output is interpreted as a percent, 5.7% in this case.

Looking at the darts documentation for the backtest() function, the default metric is MAPE. And looking at the actual darts code for the mape() function:

`100.0 * np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_hat) / y_true))`

The 100 in the beginning means the value has already been converted to a percent for you, thus a 5.7% MAPE is the correct interpretation.